# pandas convert object to type that able to do calculation

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

I have a df column data type is an object , e.g value = $45.00
I try to sum up the total amount in that column but got the following error:

output:

```
Wash_amount = df['WASHING'].sum()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Before that i tried to convert all the columns to numberic  :

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

But all the values turn to "nan", which is not i want.

So how can i convert the column value type, that i can do sum.

Or how can i a check for all the columns if contain "$" in the data, to do conversion to all as float instead of convert column by column?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the $ prefix from the string value before applying any conversion. I took the following sample data file called 'sample.csv'

```
date,Washing
12/01/1927,$251.66
01/01/1928,$250.37
02/01/1928,$248.84
03/01/1928,$277.96
04/01/1928,$284.74
05/01/1928,$286.66
06/01/1928,$275.94
07/01/1928,$280.12
08/01/1928,$300.88
09/01/1928,$301.25
10/01/1928,$310.74
11/01/1928,$348.01
12/01/1928,$351.05
01/01/1929,$371.09
02/01/1929,$368.93
```

Then the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("sample.csv"))

df['Washing'] = df['Washing'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('$'))
print(df.head())
df.Washing = df.Washing.astype('float')
print(df.dtypes)
Wash_amount = df['Washing'].sum()
print(Wash_amount)
```

Comment: df['Washing'] = df['Washing'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('$'))    give this error :   AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Comment: The lstrip would apply on  dtype: object. So, please apply the lstrip on column first and then subsequently convert it to 'float'. Please follow the order of steps in the sample code given

Comment: Hi yes, i following the step by step ?

Comment: the column is object type

Comment: Please check if the values contain any other characters other than digits. If it contains any other letter / special character it will not work

Comment: Hi, i have uploaded the data image, pls see my original post.

Comment: Oh, because some row are nan ?

Comment: Yes. Please use df = df.fillna('0') immediately after read_csv

Comment: Thanks, it work now without anymore error. Next is how can i do the same for all columns with "$" without the need to convert one by one?

Comment: Please use df = df.replace({'\$': ''}, regex=True) after the df = df.fillna('0') and then remove the lstrip statement from the code.